# Hide span element on file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script that replaces a background image with the image about to be uploaded.

You can see an example here: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vafk2Lhy/1/)**.

However, I'd like to hide the span (`.form-file-upload span`) so it doesn't have that ugly white block across the image. How do I do this?

Here's my current code:

```js
$("input[name='FileOne']").on("change", function(event1) {
      src1 = URL.createObjectURL(event1.target.files[0]);
      document.querySelector("[for=FileOne]").style.backgroundImage = 'url('+src1+')';
});
```

```css
.form-file-upload-container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-top: 12px
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
    .form-file-upload-container {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px
    }
}

.form-file-upload {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 48.5%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 3%
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
    .form-file-upload {
        width: 31.3333%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .form-file-upload {
        width: 22.75%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .form-file-upload {
        width: 14.1666667%;
        margin-right: 2%
    }
}

.form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
        margin-right: 3%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
        margin-right: 2%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 450px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 0
    }
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 3%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 2%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 750px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
        margin-right: 0
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
        margin-right: 2%
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
    .form-file-upload:nth-child(6n) {
        margin-right: 0
    }
}

.form-file-upload-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 133.33333%
}

.form-file-upload label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #AFAFB4;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #AFAFB4;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
    transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease
}

.form-file-upload span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%)
}

.form-file-upload span:before {
    content: '';
    background: url(../img/image-upload-icon.png) no-repeat center center #fff;
    background: url(../img/image-upload-icon.svg) no-repeat center center #fff;
    background-size: 65px 56px;
    display: block;
    width: 65px;
    height: 56px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px
}

.form-file-upload input {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1
}

.form-file-upload .close {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -13px;
    right: -13px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 26px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 3;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
    -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
    transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-file-upload">
<div class="form-file-upload-inner">
        <label for="FileOne"><span>Select Image</span></label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileOne" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileOne" aria-invalid="false" /></span><button class="close" type="button"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide `.form-file-upload span` using `document.querySelector(".form-file-upload span").style.display= 'none';` when file is selected

```js
$("input[type='file']").on("change", function(event1) {
  src1 = URL.createObjectURL(event1.target.files[0]);
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("label").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + src1 + ')';
  this.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector("label span").style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
.form-file-upload-container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .form-file-upload-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px
  }
}
.form-file-upload {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 48.5%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 31.3333%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 22.75%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 14.1666667%;
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
.form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-right: 0
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 3%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 3%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(6n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
.form-file-upload-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 133.33333%
}
.form-file-upload label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #AFAFB4;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #AFAFB4;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease
}
.form-file-upload span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
.form-file-upload span:before {
  content: '';
  background: url(../img/image-upload-icon.png) no-repeat center center #fff;
  background: url(../img/image-upload-icon.svg) no-repeat center center #fff;
  background-size: 65px 56px;
  display: block;
  width: 65px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
.form-file-upload input {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1
}
.form-file-upload .close {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  right: -13px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <div class="form-file-upload-inner">
    <label for="FileOne"><span>Select Image</span>
    </label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileOne" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileOne" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    <button class="close" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <div class="form-file-upload-inner">
    <label for="FileTwo"><span>Select Image</span>
    </label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileTwo" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileTwo" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    <button class="close" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <div class="form-file-upload-inner">
    <label for="FileThree"><span>Select Image</span>
    </label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileThree" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileThree" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    <button class="close" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Out of interest, will this work if my form has multiple files fields?

Comment: I have updated multiple uploads in the answer. this will work even if you have multiple set of image uploads

Comment: Such a nice, clean solution - thank you, @jafarbtech :-D

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/vafk2Lhy/2/

```
 $("input[name='FileOne']").on("change", function(event1) {
    src1 = URL.createObjectURL(event1.target.files[0]);
    document.querySelector("[for=FileOne]").style.backgroundImage = 'url('+src1+')';
  if(src1)
     document.getElementById("holder").style.display = "none";
 });
```

Find the file if present hide the span

Comment: Will this work if I have multiple file upload fields on one form? Thank you

Comment: @michaelmcgurk You can control that in this condition  if(src1) currently src1 checks for [0] file you can replace this condition by whatever you want may be event1.target.files.length > 0 then hide else if no file selected then an else condition to  .display = "block" :)

Comment: Thank you, Vinod :-) I had to change it to this but got it working: https://jsfiddle.net/vafk2Lhy/3/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `background-image` of `span:before` `css` pseudo element

```js
$("input[name='FileOne']").on("change", function(event1) {
  src1 = URL.createObjectURL(event1.target.files[0]);
  document.querySelector("[for=FileOne]").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + src1 + ')';
  
});
```

```css
.form-file-upload-container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px
}
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .form-file-upload-container {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px
  }
}
.form-file-upload {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 48.5%;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 31.3333%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 22.75%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload {
    width: 14.1666667%;
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
.form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-right: 0
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 3%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 450px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 3%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 750px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 2%
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .form-file-upload:nth-child(6n) {
    margin-right: 0
  }
}
.form-file-upload-inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 133.33333%
}
.form-file-upload label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #AFAFB4;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #AFAFB4;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.2s ease
}
.form-file-upload span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
.form-file-upload span:before {
  content: '';
  background-size: 65px 56px;
  display: block;
  width: 65px;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 5px
}
.form-file-upload input {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1
}
.form-file-upload .close {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  right: -13px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  background: white;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, color 0.2s ease
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <div class="form-file-upload-inner">
    <label for="FileOne"><span>Select Image</span>
    </label><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap FileOne"><input type="file" name="FileOne" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="FileOne" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
    <button class="close" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I were to have more than one file field, would this still work?

Comment: Yes. You can alternatively set `background` to a transparent image, or adjust `background-size` to `0px 0px`